# HTML Form is not printing right from PHP page?

Tags: php, html

I have an html page that collects data using a form with the multiple attribute, but when I try to echo out the data on the PHP page, it only echos out the last item selected.

```
  <select name="cars" multiple>
   <option value="car1"> BMW </option>
   <option value="car2"> TOYOTA </option>
   <option value="car3"> HONDA </option>
```

If I select BMW and TOYOTA, and try to  `echo $_POST['cars'];` all it echos out is TOYOTA and not BMW. How do I get it to echo out everything that is selected?

Comment: $_POST['cars'] is an array. try to loop it to get all the values

Comment: <select name="cars[]" multiple>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make select name as array type. like this and `print_r($_POST['cars']);`

```
<select name="cars[]" multiple>
   <option value="car1"> BMW </option>
   <option value="car2"> TOYOTA </option>
   <option value="car3"> HONDA </option>
```

Comment: don't forget </select>  :)

Comment: @Vbudo I just copy from the question and answered. Anyhow, I take note your point.